# Laravel validation rule for multiple value

Tags: laravel, validation

I have two table deliveries(id,name) and delivery_items(id,delivery_id,name,counter_num).

Is it possible to set a validation rule that states that for the specified delivery_id must not be two of the same counter_num.

This rule under is that there can be only one value in the table delivery_items

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'counter_num' => 'required|unique:delivery_items,counter_num'
        ];
    }
```

I would like to set a rule in which the values in the column counter_num can exist multiple of the same values but for the selected delivery_id must not be the same values

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'counter_num' => 'required|unique:delivery_items,counter_num,delivery_id'
        ];
    }
```

Example of my table

| id | delivery_id | counter_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 1 | 124 |
| 3 | 2 | 124 |
| 4 | 2 | 125 |
| 5 | 2 | 126 |

Is it feasible like this?

Comment: its written in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique @Adding Additional Where Clauses:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to ensure that the combination of `delivery_id` and `counter_num` is unique? I believe you can check that by using the `Rule` class with a `where()` callback to access the unique rule:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules(): array
{
    $id = $this->get('delivery_id');

    return [
        'counter_num' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('delivery_items')
                ->where(fn($q) => $q->where('delivery_id', $id)),
        ],
    ];
}
```

More information in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique).